# Как запретить выделять и редактировать TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Мне необходимо выделить строку в таблице и затем "заблокировать" выделение и редактирование других строк до определенного действия. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант: `tableView.setDisable(true);`

Comment: Всё круто, спасибо! Есть нюанс, можно ли сделать "блокировку таблицы" немного прозрачнее? Записи таблицы не совсем хорошо видны

Comment: @VladislavSolopov Можно с помощью `css`: `.table-view:disabled{-fx-opacity:1,0;}`

Comment: Без проблем, здесь нужно тогда поработать над стилями для состояния disable: .table-view:disabled{ -fx-opacity: 1.0;}, или же без файла css: table-vew.setDisable(true);
        table-vew.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0;");